Pinescript - Realtime close value in the past
When using my indicator, I would like to write the realtime price of a realtime candle in a var and use it later for price calculations. The problem is, however, if I write the price like this:
varip float myvar = close
in a realtime candle, the value is filled with the actual last close of the candle as soon as the candle is no longer a realtime candle, so that later, when I want to access the price, I always get the candle close price and not the close price that was the price in the realtime candle when my indicator reacted. How can I write the realtime candle price in the middle of the candle in a var so that I can calculate exactly this price later without just getting the end close of the candle.

You need to conditoinally save the value. Something like below:
varip bool is_written = false
varip flaot price = na

if (your_condition and not is_written)
    price := close
    is_written := true

While in theory this would work, if you trigger any re-execution of the script (refresh your page, change a user input, change timeframe, change ticker etc.), you will lose this data.

Thanks for the info. That's exactly how I did it. And it works as long as it's a real-time candle. But when the next candle is called, the value jumps to the last close of the real-time candle and the value in the var is no longer correct. Can it help to save the real-time value in another var?
